# New line and no indent after \paragraph?

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, indentation, koma-script

I tried to use a `\paragraph`-environment, but I do want a new line after the title and no indent in the first textline.

New line is easy, but the first line is indented even if I use `\noindent`, `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` and `\hangafter=0`

I extracted an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\hangafter=0

\begin{document}
    \subsection{subsection}
        \blindtext
    %\noindent %does not bring any effect
    \paragraph{paragraphNewline\newline}
        \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The first block is ok, but the second is not.
I expect to try a `\renewcommand` / `\renewenvironment`, but I do not know what to write in.

In general: Is there an overview, where I can see the implementation of LaTeX-commands and -environments?

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/indent-all-but-first-lines-of-paragraph?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you asked, here's how you would redefine `\paragraph`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
  {0.01pt}%
  {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@paragraph}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \subsection{subsection}
        \blindtext
    \paragraph{paragraph}
        \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The original definition is in your class file – here, [`scrreprt.cls`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrreprt.cls). It uses the LaTeX command `\@startsection`, which is described in [source2e](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf). The `0.01pt` is the amount of space to insert between the heading and text. As described in source2e, section `ltsect.dtx`, it must be above zero if you *don't* want a run-in head.

Comment: worked great :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of tweaking several different values and adding newlines manually, I would recommend setting `parindent` to zero in the documentclass parameters, and to use the `titlesec` package to give a paragraph heading the desired format.

```
\documentclass[parindent=0pt,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {}

\begin{document}
    \subsection{subsection}
        \blindtext
    \paragraph{paragraphNewline}
        \blindtext
\end{document}
```

See the [`titlesec`](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) documentation for a wealth of formatting options.

Comment: If you want to disable indentation in KOMA-Script, the best option is `parskip=half` or `parskip=full`. The option `parindent` is obsolete, and `parindent=0pt` did nothing on my installation.

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: @Wiebke: "Did not help" does not help. Anyway, glad you found a solution. ;-)

Comment: @rdhs: `parskip` adds vertical space, which might not be desired...?

Comment: To change the vertical spacing using `titlesec` you could use, e.g., `\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1ex}{-\parskip}`. Or to have the entire document with no skips *and* no indents, `\parskip=0pt` – but that's just bad typography.

Comment: This solution adds vertical space after the heading of the paragraph.
Can you maybe comment on what is doing what in your latex code?