# Indent text after line 1

Tags: indentation, theorems, paragraphs

How can I accomplish something like this:

[image]

Basically, I want my text to be "indented" after the first line. It would be great if somebody knew an answer. Ideally I would like to do this, because I want my theorems/proofs to look like this:

[image]

In my opinion, it makes the whole format much clearer.

Comment: have a look at this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/indent-all-but-first-lines-of-paragraph?rq=1

Comment: It seems \hangindent1em does the job perfectly. Thanks a lot prettygully. :)

Comment: The fact that something is easily doable with a word processor doesn't mean it's typographycally sound. I always teach this golden rule: if something is not easy to attain with LaTeX, then it's probably wrong. ;-)

Comment: If you are doing this sort of indent for every X (theorem, etc., etc.), it is better to use/design an environment that achieves what you want.  This will make modifying the style *much* easier to maintain.  Manual intervention each time is best suited for things like word processors (and even then there are 'styles' or something that one can use for a similar reason).

Answer (score 8):

Using the `enumitem` package, you can fairly easily muck around with the dimensions of a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}[label={},itemindent=-2em,leftmargin=2em]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to do this for every paragraph, that's a bit more involved.

It doesn't appear that `amsthm`, or even `thm-tools`, provide the means for *easily* creating a theorem with a hanging indent.  But, *theorem-like* environments are built up from `\trivlist`.  So, if you know what you want, you can define your own theorem style from a `list` environment.  You'll probably also want to define your own counter to go with it.

To begin to get a theorem-like structure, you can do something like the following:

```
\newcounter{mytheoremcounter}[chapter]%% to number within chapters
\newenvironment{mytheorem}
    {\refstepcounter{mytheoremcounter}%% so ref/labels work as you expect
     \begin{list}
           {\bfseries\upshape Theorem \arabic{mytheoremcounter}.}
           {\setlength{\labelwidth=2em}
            \em%
          }
          \item 
    }
    {\end{list}}
```

[image]

Per @GonzaloMedina 
You can get the `amsthm` package to work for this purpose.  You cleverly sneak the formatting through the argument of a `\newtheoremstyle` for the body font.  As in

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mythrm}%
    {0pt}{0pt}
    {\hangindent 2.5em}% body font
    {}
    {\bfseries}
    {.}% punctuation
    {0.5em}
    {}
\theoremstyle{mythrm}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Hi}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{mytheorem}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mytheorem}

A second theorem
\begin{mytheorem}{}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mytheorem}

\chapter{There}


\begin{mytheorem}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mytheorem}

A second theorem
\begin{mytheorem}{}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mytheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your affirmation about `amsthm` is not entirely true, as the following example shows (sorry, but the code formatting gets lost in comments): `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{hindent}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}
  {\hangindent 2.5em}{}
  {\bfseries}{:}
  {.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{hindent}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina very clever.  Why not make that another answer?

Comment: I think it would be better if you add this possibility to your answer, to make it comprehensive. What do you think?