# Indent Theorem like \hangindent, but for multiple paragraphs

Tags: spacing, indentation, theorems, paragraphs

I would like to create a theorem style which indents the theorem exactly like a \hangindent would do, expect that the indention should continue for **all paragraphs of the theorem**.

For example:

```
Theorem 1.2.3: Lipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit, 
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

    Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, 
    nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate ...
```

I tried this, but it does not work correctly:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\let\thm\relax
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    bodyfont=\normalfont\leftskip2.5em,
    headindent={-2.5em}
]{INDENTthm}
\declaretheorem[
    within=section,
    style=INDENTthm,
    name=Theorem
]{thm}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[2]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

What happens is that the theorem header suddenly has a negative indention relative to the page, i.e. starts just a little to the left of the actual page, although I would expect "2.5em-2.5em=0em"... :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: is there anything helpful in the question [Indent text after line 1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99344/)?

Comment: The solution given there for amsthm/thmtools actually uses \hangintent to create the indention, which is reset after the first paragraph of the theorem (as \hangindent only lasts for one paragraph). This is what I wanted to work around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a fan of this kind of indentation. However no solution using `\leftskip` is good, since theorems are implemented as lists; try adding an `enumerate` environment to your theorem and see.

Your problem is that you use *two* different ems: the medium series one and the boldface one, which are different. So the two facts require a different solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\kern-2.5em\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  headindent=0pt,
]{INDENTthm}
\declaretheorem[
  within=section,
  style=INDENTthm,
  name=Theorem
]{thm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}{%
  \patchcmd\@thm
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin2.5em\itemindent-15em}}
    {}{}%
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endthm{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

This does the patch only for the `thm` environment. As [Zhen Lin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4946/zhen-lin) correctly remarks in a comment, the

```
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endthm{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
```

line for a theorem named `lemma` should become

```
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endlemma{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
```

[image]

If one has several theorem-like environments and all should share the hanging indentation, then it's better to abstract the procedure. The `\xdeclaretheorem` command defined below will do just that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
  {\trivlist}
  {\list{}{\leftmargin2.5em\itemindent-15em}}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\xdeclaretheorem}[2][]{%
  \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname thmt@original@end#2\endcsname
    {\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\kern-2.5em\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  headindent=0pt,
]{INDENTthm}

\xdeclaretheorem[
  within=section,
  style=INDENTthm,
  name=Theorem
]{thm}

\xdeclaretheorem[
  sibling=thm,
  style=INDENTthm,
  name=Lemma
]{lem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case only *some* theorem-like environment should have hanging indentation the code

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{#2}{%
  \patchcmd\@thm
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin2.5em\itemindent-15em}}
    {}{}%
}
```

should be added to the definition of `\xdeclaretheorem` and the global patch removed. Of course, non indented environments should use `\declaretheorem`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution.
What is the "\itemindent-15em" actually needed for?

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that the last three characters in `\thmt@original@endthm` should also be replaced with the environment name, to prevent problems with “too much nesting”...

Comment: Note that the patch has to be delayed if `hyperref` is used, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550180/4427

Comment: Is the `AtBeginEnvironment{thm}` in your first code for the same purpose as your last comment, namely to delay the patch? If so, is there a preference between that and `AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @user21820 There's a big difference! The code in `\AtBeginEnvironment{thm}` is executed every time `\begin{thm}` is performed (and the code loses its effects at `\end{thm}`).

Comment: I know that, but why do you need to patch `\@thm` more than once? Oh I see you only wanted to patch `\thm`...

Comment: Maybe also note in your post that if one uses `cleveref` then one needs to patch `\cref@thmnoarg` and `\cref@thmoptarg` instead of `\@thm`? I just spent a long while trying to figure out why my patch was always failing...

Answer (score 0):

I've hardwired the indents, but you should be able to change them to an argument, and restore them to their original

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 1em
\let\svpar\par
\newenvironment{hang}{\hangindent 0.7in\def\par{\svpar\hangindent
0.7in\parindent 0.7in}}
{\let\par\svpar\parindent 0in}
\begin{document}

non-indented text

\begin{hang}
erew ewr ewr ew rwe fsgfkgwerlktmn gghlkrgtkj rgngmn
krwghj,gn ghrgtkrkltgrkgfremgrtgklrwtklrgfd,m srjhgksg 

continuing test to new paragraph

finally ending test now
\end{hang}

non-indent

\end{document}
```

[image]