# What's the differences between the kernel commands \trivlist and \list?

Tags: macros, lists, latex-base

LaTeX defines the two environments `\trivlist` and `\list`. Both can be used creating own environments.

**What exactly is the differences between `\trivlist` and `\list`?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\list` is less triv(ial) than `\trivlist`.

Essentially `\list` has hooks for setting the label format which trivlist doesn't use (as it's normally used in things like center where the label/item is hidden, or theorems where there is only one item).

It's premature optimisation in a way: @egreg had to [patch a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106572/indent-theorem-like-hangindent-but-for-multiple-paragraphs/106582#106582) in an answer the other day to use list not trivlist so that the formatting could be changed. Had the original used list it would have been a trivial setting.