# Theorems with hanging indentation, also working with itemize

Tags: indentation, theorems, amsthm

I've been trying numerous ways to have a hanging indentation in my theorems. I'm using `amsthm` to define my own theorem styles.

What I want is the theorem to indent after line 1 like this:

```
Text before theorem.
Theorem 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pellentes
    nibh dapibus sem pharetra, eu accumsan nibh pretium. Integer auctor ornare nibh. 
    Morbi magna neque, luctus maximus metus ut, fermentum aliquet odio. Ut bibendum.
      - List item 1
      - List item 2
    Lectus sed nibh ultrices porta. Curabitur enim leo, imperdiet at mauris tempus.
More text after theorem
```

with the source code of this looking like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem} .... %Theorem style here
%\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
Text before theorem.
\begin{thm} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pellentes
nibh dapibus sem pharetra, eu accumsan nibh pretium. Integer auctor ornare nibh.
Morbi magna neque, luctus maximus metus ut, fermentum aliquet odio. Ut bibendum.
\begin{itemize}
\item List item 1
\item List item 2
\end{itemize}
Lectus sed nibh ultrices porta. Curabitur enim leo, imperdiet at mauris tempus.
\end{thm}
More text after theorem
\end{document}
```

As mentioned I've tried numerous ways, but one (using `\hangindent`) doesn't work with itemize, others work for only one paragraph.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106572/indent-theorem-like-hangindent-but-for-multiple-paragraphs ?

Comment: I had not, seems to work indeed. One problem, I've got something like 15 different theorems, do I have to declare the `AtBeginEnvironment{...} ...` from the first answer for every theorem, or is there a clever way to do this for all?

Comment: The update is on-line.