# How to manipulate theorem body text indentation (using amsthm package)?

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I would like to create the following formatting for summing up hypotheses (I am using the `report` documentclass):

```
Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. 

     Hypothesis 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
     Phasellus iaculis imperdiet blandit. 

Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text. Body text.
```

So far this is what I have managed to come up with (I'm trying to do it with the `amsthm` package):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm, top=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newtheoremstyle{hypothesis}
    {5pt}
    {5pt}
    {\itshape} 
    {1cm} 
    {\bfseries} 
    {} 
    {.5em}
    {}
\theoremstyle{hypothesis}
\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{hypo}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis imperdiet blandit.
\end{hypo}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

As you can see I'm almost there. The only thing I still need now is that the hypothesis body text has the same indentation as the hypothesis head (i.e. when the hypothesis body continues on a new line, that line has to begin at the same point that the hypothesis head begins).

I feel like it has to be something very simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106582/4427

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
  {\trivlist}
  {\list{}{\theoremmargins}}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\xdeclaretheorem}[2][]{%
  \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname thmt@original@end#2\endcsname
    {\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}
\newcommand{\theoremmargins}{\leftmargin=0pt}
\newcommand{\theoremindent}{\leftmargin=2.5em\rightmargin=2.5em}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  headindent=0pt,
]{INDENTthm}

\xdeclaretheorem[
  preheadhook=\let\theoremmargins\theoremindent,
  within=section,
  style=INDENTthm,
  name=Hypothesis
]{hyp}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Theorem
]{thm}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thm}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{hyp}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{hyp}
\end{document}
```

As usual, `showframe` is just for showing the text block boundaries.

[image]

Comment: Hi egreg, I prefer your solution because it is more aesthetically pleasing to me personally. However, I can't seem to get rid of the "0.1" after Hypothesis. Is there a way to get it to count from 1?

Comment: @idix That's obtained by removing `within=section`

Comment: Hi, sorry to come back to this, but I would like to nest the hypotheses like this: Hypothesis 1.1 
The thing is that I would like to do this only with certain hypotheses. For instance, Hypothesis 1 would be on its own, and would only read `Hypothesis 1`. But Hypothesis 2 would have two subhypotheses so it would have to read `Hypothesis 2` and its subhypotheses would read `Hypothesis 2.1` and `Hypothesis 2.2`

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straightforward to do it with `ntheorem`; there a predefined length `\theoremindent`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm, top=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremindent1\parindent
\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{hypo}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis imperdiet blandit.
\end{hypo}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]