# Leftmargin for theorems with thmtools-package

Tags: thmtools, leftmargin

Is there an easy way to set a left margin with the `thmtools-package`?

```
\documentclass[ngerman, parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%
\declaretheoremstyle[%
    spaceabove=9pt,%
    spacebelow=9pt,%
    headfont=\normalfont\itshape,%
    postheadspace=1em,%
    headpunct={},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\small,
]{myremark}
%
\declaretheorem[style=myremark, title=Anmerkung, numbered=no]{remark}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{remark}
This remark should have a left margin of, e.g. 10pt. 
But how to do this?
With ntheorem-package I just use \verb|\theoremindent10pt|
\end{remark}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245218/208544

Comment: Overlocked it, thank you. But not the easiest way.

Comment: If you're using a KOMA class already you can try hooking an `addmargin` environment to the beginning and ending of `remark`, like `\AddToHook{env/remark/before}{\begin{addmargin}[10pt]{0pt}}` and
`\AddToHook{env/remark/after}{\end{addmargin}}`. Might need to adjust vertical spacing