# Indent theorem body (excluding the title)

Tags: environments, indentation, theorems

I'd like to define custom environments in which the body is indented in contrast to the body/the first line of the environment. An example could look like this

[image]

In particular not every environment should be indented. How can I approach this problem? I'm using `amsthm`. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Please show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of how your currently define/use your environent. Please also be more specific about "in particular not every environment should be indented".

Comment: This question covers the same request: [Indent Theorem like \hangindent, but for multiple paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106572/579)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}%
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lemma}{\par\hangindent=2.5em}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lemma}{\par}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{lemma}{2}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{lemma}
Sei $\mathcal{M}_{μ}$ die Familie der $\mu$-meßbaren Teilmengen von $X$. Dann ist $\mathcal{M}_{μ}$ eine $\sigma$-Algebra über $X$, und $\mu$ eingeschränkt auf $\mathcal{M}_{μ}$ ist ein (positives) Maß auf $\mathcal{M}_{μ}$.
\end{lemma}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]