# Theorem environment identation error with hyperref

Tags: fonts, hyperref, koma-script, theorems

So I want to indent my theorem text like on this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106572/indent-theorem-like-hangindent-but-for-multiple-paragraphs) but when I use `\usepackage{hyperref}`, the theorem name gets shifted out of the document frame. E.g.

```
\documentclass[
    toc=chapterentrydotfill,
    numbers=endperiod
    ]
    {scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\swapnumbers

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin2.5em\itemindent-15em}}
    {}{}
\newcommand{\xdeclaretheorem}[2][]{%
    \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}%
    \expandafter\patchcmd\csname thmt@original@end#2\endcsname
    {\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\kern-2.5em\bfseries,
    headpunct = {.},
    notebraces = {[}{]},
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    postheadspace = 5pt,
    spacebelow = 5pt,
    spaceabove = 5pt]{thms}

\xdeclaretheorem[style = thms, name = Theorem, numberwithin = chapter]{thm}
\xdeclaretheorem[style = thms, name = Lemma, sibling = thm]{lem}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
        \begin{lem}
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{lem}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

instead of

[image]

The second picture is the same code as above, but with the hyperref package removed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome on SE, @HannaBloom! In the above MWE there is no `hyperref` command. Could you include it? Because the position of this command within the document is relevant.

Comment: @tanGIS thanks! it was all the way at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hyperref` package does its own patching to `\@thm`, so we need to delay ours after it.

```latex
\documentclass[
  toc=chapterentrydotfill,
  numbers=endperiod
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\swapnumbers

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{% we need to wait after hyperref has done its own patching
  \patchcmd\@thm
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin2.5em\itemindent-15em}}
    {}{}%
}
\newcommand{\xdeclaretheorem}[2][]{%
    \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}%
    \expandafter\patchcmd\csname thmt@original@end#2\endcsname
    {\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\kern-2.5em\bfseries,
    headpunct = {.},
    notebraces = {[}{]},
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    postheadspace = 5pt,
    spacebelow = 5pt,
    spaceabove = 5pt]{thms}

\xdeclaretheorem[style = thms, name = Theorem, numberwithin = chapter]{thm}
\xdeclaretheorem[style = thms, name = Lemma, sibling = thm]{lem}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{lem}\label{test}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{lem}

\ref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's awesome, thanks!